# Subtract all the rows from the value of first row in a MySQL column

Tags: mysql

This is my Select query

```
Select
  snpc_stats.gamedetail.Player,
  Sum(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Points + snpc_stats.gamedetail.Hits) As TotalPoints,
  COUNT(*) As 'Games Played',
  Sum(If(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Finish = 1, 1, 0)) As Wins,
  Sum(If(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Finish = 2, 1, 0)) As Second,
  Sum(If(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Finish = 3, 1, 0)) As Third,
  Round(Avg(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Finish),2) As 'Average Finish',
  Sum(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Hits) As `Total Hits`, 
  Sum(snpc_stats.gamedetail.ChampFund) As ChampFund,
  Sum(snpc_stats.games.BuyIn) + (snpc_stats.gamedetail.ChampFund) As Cost,
  Sum(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Winnings) As Winnings,
  Sum(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Winnings) - (snpc_stats.games.BuyIn) - (snpc_stats.gamedetail.ChampFund) As 'Total Winnings',
  COUNT(snpc_stats.games.Round) As round

From
  snpc_stats.gamedetail Inner Join
  snpc_stats.games On snpc_stats.games.GameID =
  snpc_stats.gamedetail.GamesID

Where
  snpc_stats.games.Season = '2015 Season'

Group By
  snpc_stats.gamedetail.Player, snpc_stats.games.Season

Order By
  TotalPoints Desc
```

After the TotalPoints Column I like to add a column that show the amount of points each player trails behind the leader, like the table below:

```
Rank | Player | Total Points | Points Behind
 1      Bill       164            -
 2       Al        152            -12
 3       Ed        151            -13
 4      Jill       123            -41
 5      Bob        121            -43
 6      Joe        102            -62
 7      Dave        82            -82
 8      Rob         60            -104
 9      Doug        60            -104
10      Don         51            -113
11      Dan         30            -134
```

Any help would be so appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**solution (1)**
If you are using a server side language that connects to the database and runs the query, you can preserve total points value of first row in some variable and subtracting all the following rows from it
**solution (2)**
make a sub query that returns total points of the first row and use it in the selection part of the query

```html
Select
  snpc_stats.gamedetail.Player,
  Sum(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Points + snpc_stats.gamedetail.Hits) As TotalPoints, 
  (Sum(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Points + snpc_stats.gamedetail.Hits) - (Select Sum(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Points + snpc_stats.gamedetail.Hits) From snpc_stats.gamedetail Inner Join snpc_stats.games On snpc_stats.games.GameID = snpc_stats.gamedetail.GamesID Where snpc_stats.games.Season = '2015 Season' Group By snpc_stats.gamedetail.Player, snpc_stats.games.Seaso Order By Sum(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Points + snpc_stats.gamedetail.Hits) Desc Limit 1)) As Points Behind,
  COUNT(*) As 'Games Played',
  Sum(If(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Finish = 1, 1, 0)) As Wins,
  Sum(If(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Finish = 2, 1, 0)) As Second,
  Sum(If(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Finish = 3, 1, 0)) As Third,
  Round(Avg(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Finish),2) As 'Average Finish',
  Sum(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Hits) As `Total Hits`, 
  Sum(snpc_stats.gamedetail.ChampFund) As ChampFund,
  Sum(snpc_stats.games.BuyIn) + (snpc_stats.gamedetail.ChampFund) As Cost,
  Sum(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Winnings) As Winnings,
  Sum(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Winnings) - (snpc_stats.games.BuyIn) - (snpc_stats.gamedetail.ChampFund) As 'Total Winnings',
  COUNT(snpc_stats.games.Round) As round
From
  snpc_stats.gamedetail Inner Join
  snpc_stats.games On snpc_stats.games.GameID =
  snpc_stats.gamedetail.GamesID
Where
  snpc_stats.games.Season = '2015 Season'
Group By
  snpc_stats.gamedetail.Player, snpc_stats.games.Season
Order By
  TotalPoints Desc
```

Comment: When I use your select statement I get "Reference 'TotalPoints' not supported (reference to group function)"

Comment: can you post the schema of the two tables "gamedetail" and "games"

Comment: I figured out my mistake...
That did the trick. It works fantastic! I appreciate your help, and will definitely try to figure out exactly what's going on there so I can learn from it!'
Thank you very much Abdo Adel!

Comment: btw, there is nothing special going there, it's the same query that you have written except that it returns only the total points value **"select Sum(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Points + snpc_stats.gamedetail.Hits)"** of the first row only **"limit 1"**, then i use that value to subtract it from Total Points